# Excel macro to move data from one sheet to another based column name and cell content

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet1 with a column labeled participant and columns labeled 1-20 (experiment ID numbers).

I have another worksheet2 with data of participants (column) and the experiments (column) they participated in.

What I need to do is place an "X", on worksheet1, in the corresponding cells from worksheet2.

Here are some images that show what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pivot table.  It will get you exactly what you are looking for.

```
Row Label: Participant
Col Label: Experiment
Values: Count of Experiment
```

Then you would need to change all the "1"s to "X" with find/replace (either manually or with macro):

```
Range(pivottablecells).Replace("1", "X")
```

Comment: Have you had any success with this method?